# Cron Job - Command to delete all .flv files everyday

Tags: shell, command-line, file, cron, fedora

I have this command that I run everyday via cron:

```
find /home/get/public_html/videos -daystart -maxdepth 0 
-mtime +1 -type f -name "*.flv" |xargs rm -f
```

The problem is that it doesn't delete the .flv files in a directory that are  1 or more days old.

How can I correct the above command?

EDIT: Paul - the command "ls -l /home/get/public_html/videos" results in 2000+ files but here is 2 of them that should be deleted:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 get get   3501188 Jan  4 15:24 f486cf0a2b6bb40e4c50c991785084131231104229.flv
-rw-r--r--  1 get get  10657314 Jan  4 17:51 f5f1490ddaa11a663686f9d06fb37d981231112941.flv
```

Comment: What does it do? Does it delete older files, not delete files, give an error ....?

Comment: It doesn't delete anything and it returns nothing because I think it didn't find anything. No errors though.

Comment: Can you add the result of ls -l /home/get/public_html/videos to your question?

Comment: What happens if you make it -maxdepth 1, as others have suggested? (and just -print, not xargs for now!)? (I don't have GNU find on the Unix systems accessible to me)

Comment: Your are right Paul, it works with -maxdepth 1 like Vinko Vrsalovic said. It works now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use -print0 on find and -0 in xargs in case one file has an uncommon name.

Also, you want to use -maxdepth 1 to actually find something in the specified directory.

-maxdepth 0 means it'll only find in the directories listed in the command line, it won't check the contents of those directories.

Comment: Correct -maxdepth 1 is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, if you have a directory `/home/get/public_html/videos/foo` it doesn't delete the files in them? That would be because you have the `-maxdepth 0` argument set, which prevents `find` from descending into subdirectories.

Comment: I want the command to search in the directory "videos" and not go into any subfolders.

Does that mean I should remove "-maxdepth 1"?

Comment: No, in that case -maxdepth 1 is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
-maxdepth 1
```